# Apex login fail default username password

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

i installed oracleEX 11g, then i tried to login to apex 
[tutorials](http://www.easyapex.com/index.php?p=503)

i failed to login using the default admin/admin
 system/ my password

see the screenshot

[image]
please help me to login to apex .
i appreciate any suggestion

Comment: http://mohammadfawzy.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/oracle-apex-the-server-requires-a-username-and-password-the-server-says-xdb/

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Thanks , that what i used to solve it , i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Enable network services (ACL) and XML DB HTTP server

Re enable the Oracle XML DB HTTP Server port (8383):

`EXEC dbms_xdb.sethttpport(8383);`

Enable remote HTTP connections (optional):

`EXEC dbms_xdb.setListenerLocalAccess(l_access => FALSE);`

By default, the ability to interact with network services is disabled in Oracle Database 11g. Therefore, you must use the DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN package to grant connect privileges to any host for the APEX_040200 database user:

```
`DECLARE
ACL_PATH VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
-- Look for the ACL currently assigned to '*' and give APEX_040200
-- the "connect" privilege if APEX_040200
-- does not have the privilege yet.
SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
WHERE HOST = '*' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;
IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_040200',
'connect') IS NULL THEN
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
'APEX_040200', TRUE, 'connect');
END IF;
EXCEPTION
-- When no ACL has been assigned to '*'.
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('power_users.xml',
'ACL that lets power users to connect to everywhere',
'APEX_040200', TRUE, 'connect');
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('power_users.xml','*');
END;
/
COMMIT;`
```

Comment: i appreciate your help, this has been solved in the comments
http://mohammadfawzy.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/oracle-apex-the-server-requires-a-username-and-password-the-server-says-xdb/